# How to get a Lipo to discharge at 3volts continuously

Tags: batteries, motor, lipo, volts

So let me start off by saying I'm brand new at this, but I'd like to learn. I have a 3v Motor that I need to run. I want to create a way to use a rechargeable Lipo to run the motor. How can I keep a lipo battery discharging at 3volts continuously? If I am being to Vague let me know. I'll answer any questions you have. I'm also connecting the motor to a momentary switch. I want everything to be as safe as possible. Thank you again.

Comment: This is an "XY" problem - what you need to do is a run the motor, not product a constant voltage.  Motors are typically run by PWM, possibly in closed loop to achieve a desired speed.

Comment: A typical "3V" motor will do fine at 4.2V, motors are pretty tough unless it's an unusually high performance one run at its limit such as in a quadcopter.

Comment: You're right. I just tested it and my motor worked fine. Just didn't want to blow the motor. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A buck-boost regulator is designed to provide a constant voltage from a varying input voltage, such as the output of a battery pack.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a voltage regulator which takes input in the range 3V - 4.2V and outputs 3V.**

Since a Li-Po battery can have voltages between 3V to 4.2V depending upon charge level, it would make sense to use a buck-boost converter like TPS61170DRVR which can accept a voltage as low as 3V and will still output 3V.